# How to update table value when a browser is closed using php

Tags: javascript, php

When a user login ,

update play set login='1';

when logout ,

update play set login='0';

but when the user close the browser/tab without using 'logout' , How I can change the value login to '0'.

I m using this 'login' as a flag so that no 2 members cannot login with the same username. (user names are created by the admin and distributed to the students.Password is not used.)

If  a particular user logged in then first check his 'login'.
if login = 0 
then that user 'login' will be updated as 1.
else
echo already logged in.

Is there any other way to implement this.

Comment: this is not a good way to do that

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandlerinterface.php

Answer (score 1):

The easy solution is to poll the server using AJAX to keep the user logged in (unless they click logout). Change all rows to `login='0'` unless they are detected as *online* via an updated timestamp when you do the heartbeat/poll.

For example:

```
function heartbeat(){
   setTimeout(function(){
      $.ajax({ url: "http://example.com/api/heartbeat", cache: false,
      success: function(data){
        //Next beat
        heartbeat();
      }, dataType: "json"});
  }, 10000);//10secs
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    heartbeat();
});
```

More info can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10244604/php-best-practice-keep-track-of-logged-in-users/10244757) (from a previous question)

Answer (score 0):

It a pretty complex matter and there are a number of solutions in this matter

As @Loz Cherone stated and can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10244604/php-best-practice-keep-track-of-logged-in-users/10244757) you can count your users who have their broswer's page open with some ways

Also here is a discussion of this matter that you should read [conversation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181189/to-detect-if-the-user-is-closing-the-ie-browser-apart-from-onunload-event-as-it)

I think you should read them and think more what you want exactly to do so you can update your question and get some better answers :)